# divで囲んだデータを送信する

Tags: html, jsp

div要素をクリックしたらそのデータを送る。

```
<form action=“hogeAction” name=“form1”>
<div onclick=“hoge()”>
<input type =“hidden” name=“data” value=“1”>
<h2>ありゃりゃ</h2>
</form>

<script>
function hoge(){
document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

疑問なのはこれで送れているどうか
formで送れる値みたいなものはinputでしか指定できない
ほかに送るのに何かいい方法があればお願いします。

Comment: DIVの閉じタグが無いですが脱字でしょうか？`編集`から質問を修正できますのでご活用ください。

Comment: この場合DIV内の何を送りたいのでしょうか?